# Unable to perform verification using bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to use bootstrap modal on submitting the form data.However,I donot want to submit the empty form.However,When i'm using bootstrap modal to trigger on submit event on an empty form it's working instead it should stop ask me to fill the required field and then trigger the modal.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#df").text()!= '')
    {
      $("#form").submit(function(event) {
      $("#myModal").modal('show');
     });
     });

   </script>

   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="bs-example">
   <form id = "rish">
   <input type = "text" id = "df">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"></input>
   </form>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-
    dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document  
                   before closing?</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
                 dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save                  
                 changes</button>
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Porbably text() does not hold good for input elements. 
Replace text() with val() to get the value of the input. This should work.

```
if($("#df").val()!= '')
    {
      $("#rish").submit(function(event) {
      $("#myModal").modal('show');
     });
     });
```

Also change the form id to #rish from #form.

Comment: it's not showing much difference...it's not even triggering the modal

Comment: $('#form') does not exist.. The form is given the id rish.. Please check that.. That might be the solution.

Comment: yea..tried with that..couldnot make any difference!

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        if($("#df").val()!= '')
        {
          $("#rishh").submit(function(event) {
           $("#myModal").modal('show');
         });

}

else
{
    alert("hi");
}
});
    </script>   <form id = "rishh">
     <input type = "text" id = "df">   
    <input type ="submit"  name= "submit" value = "submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"></input>
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The value at #df might not be present at the time when the document is ready. You may probably enter the value later which means there is no event to trigger the modal. So instead of submitting the form when the document is ready, do the following.

```
<form id = "rish">
<input type = "text" id = "df">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="submitForm();"></input>
</form>

function submitForm()
{
   if($("#df").text()!= '')
{
  $("#rish").submit(function(event) {
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
 });
}
```

Comment: No It could hardly add a difference!